# Prove that the derivative of a polynomial that has k roots, has at least k - 1 roots

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I stumbled upon a question but I couldn't find a proper demonstration.
Here it is:

> If c<sub>1</sub> < c<sub>2</sub> < ... < c<sub>k</sub> are roots of the polynomial f(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + ... + a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup>, then f'(x) has *at least* k - 1 roots.

I thought that since the derivative lowers the degree of the polynomial by 1, then it must also have *at maximum* $k - 1$ solutions. But the statement says *at least* $k - 1$. Is my thought wrong? Could a $n - 1$ degree derivative have $k$ solution?

How would you prove it precisely?
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Hint : Rolle's theorem

Comment: "Could an $n-1$ degree derivative have $k$ solutions?" Sure - take any cubic with 3 roots (hence two stationary points) and translate it vertically by enough that it only has one root. e.g. $x^3-x + 1$ has one root, but its derivative $3x^2-1$, has two.

Comment: @Peter yes, I thought about it bc I found this proof exercise in the Rolle's theorem section. But how should I be supposed to use it?

Comment: @preferred_anon I see, thanks for the clarification

Comment: The polynomial is $$f(x)=a_0(x-c_1)^{b_1}...(x-c_k)^{b_k}$$ where $b_1, ... ,b_k$ are positive integers and $b_1+...+b_k=n.$

Comment: If we think about the graph of $f(x)$ there will be a bounded wiggly section between $c_1$ and $c_k$ as the function turns back on itself to pass through each root. When the function turns around it will have slope $0$ and there should be one between every root. Since there are $k$ roots there are $k-1$ gaps so the derivative should have $k-1$ roots. See if you can figure out how to apply Rolle's theorem from there.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks so much, now I have figured it out